# group values by id

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I have this code:

```
 function get_posts_tags($db, $start, $number_of_posts) {
    //query
    ");

    $sql -> bind_param('ii',$start, $number_of_posts);
    $sql -> execute();
    $sql -> bind_result($id_offer, $tag);

    $posts_tags = array();
    while ($sql -> fetch()) {
        $posts_tags[] = array('id_offer'=>$id_offer, 'tag'=>$tag);
    };

    $sql->close();

    var_dump($posts_tags);
}
```

output:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'id_offer' => int 77
      'tag' => string 'PHP' (length=3)
  1 => 
    array
      'id_offer' => int 77
      'tag' => string 'JAVA' (length=4)
  2 => 
    array
      'id_offer' => int 76
      'tag' => string 'PHP' (length=3)
  3 => 
    array
      'id_offer' => int 76
      'tag' => string 'JAVA' (length=4)
```

What i want is group the tags by id in the array `$posts_tags[]`. How can i do that ? At the moment what i have is a simple output of DB.

something like:

```
 array
      0 => 
        array
          'id_offer' => int 77
          'tag0' => string 'PHP' (length=3)
          'tag1' => string 'JAVA' (length=4)
      1 => 
        array
          'id_offer' => int 76
          'tag0' => string 'PHP' (length=3)
          'tag1' => string 'JAVA' (length=4)
```

...

Thanks

Comment: A piece of code got lost, I can't see the query text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this work for you?

```
array
    0 => 
        array
            'id_offer' => int 77
            'tags'     => array
                0 => string 'PHP' (length=3)
                1 => string 'JAVA' (length=4)
    1 => 
        array
            'id_offer' => int 76
            'tags'     => array
                0 => string 'PHP' (length=3)
                1 => string 'JAVA' (length=4)
```

This can be accomplished like this:

```
while ($sql -> fetch()) {
    $post_tags[$id_offer]['id_offer'] = $id_offer;
    $post_tags[$id_offer]['tags'][]   = $tag;
};

// Reset the array keys with array_values() or array_merge()
$post_tags = array_values($post_tags);
```